# Does PLA become brittle with age?

Tags: pla, print-material, filament-quality

I tried to use an old spool of PDA and the filament would keep breaking.  New filament will discolor white but stay intact when you bend it.  This old filament would break off at a clean 90 degrees when you bend it with no discoloration.  However, our new material is Hatchbox PLA and the older is a different brand.

Comment: It becomes brittle when it takes up moisture, how much depends on humidity and time. The better you store it the longer it takes to become brittle.

Comment: Duplicate of https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/1404/can-aged-pla-be-refurbished ?

Comment: There are many theories why PLA filament becomes brittle. See the link in previous comment.